# R | Mutate with condition for multiple columns

Tags: r, mean, case-when

I want to calculate the mean in a row if at least three out of six observations in the row are != NA. If four or more NA´s are present, the mean should show NA.

Example which gives me the mean, ignoring the NA´s:

```
require(dplyr)

a <- 1:10
b <- a+10
c <- a+20
d <- a+30
e <- a+40
f <- a+50

df <- data.frame(a,b,c,d,e,f)

df[2,c(1,3,4,6)] <- NA
df[5,c(1,4,6)] <- NA
df[8,c(1,2,5,6)] <- NA


df <- df %>% mutate(mean = rowMeans(df[,1:6], na.rm=TRUE))
```

I thought about the use of

> case_when

but i´m not sure how to use it correctly:

```
df <- df %>% mutate(mean = case_when( ~ rowMeans(df[,1:6], na.rm=TRUE), TRUE ~ NA))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try a `base R` solution saving the number of non `NA` values in a new variable and then use `ifelse()` for the mean:

```
#Data
a <- 1:10
b <- a+10
c <- a+20
d <- a+30
e <- a+40
f <- a+50

df <- data.frame(a,b,c,d,e,f)

df[2,c(1,3,4,6)] <- NA
df[5,c(1,4,6)] <- NA
df[8,c(1,2,5,6)] <- NA
#Code
#Count number of non NA
df$count <- rowSums( !is.na( df [,1:6]))
#Compute mean
df$Mean <- ifelse(df$count>=3,rowMeans(df [,1:6],na.rm=T),NA)
```

Output:

```
    a  b  c  d  e  f count     Mean
1   1 11 21 31 41 51     6 26.00000
2  NA 12 NA NA 42 NA     2       NA
3   3 13 23 33 43 53     6 28.00000
4   4 14 24 34 44 54     6 29.00000
5  NA 15 25 NA 45 NA     3 28.33333
6   6 16 26 36 46 56     6 31.00000
7   7 17 27 37 47 57     6 32.00000
8  NA NA 28 38 NA NA     2       NA
9   9 19 29 39 49 59     6 34.00000
10 10 20 30 40 50 60     6 35.00000
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(
    mean = case_when(
      sum(is.na(c_across())) < 4 ~ mean(c_across(), na.rm = TRUE),
      TRUE ~ NA_real_)
    ) %>% ungroup()
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 7
       a     b     c     d     e     f  mean
   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1    11    21    31    41    51  26  
 2    NA    12    NA    NA    42    NA  NA  
 3     3    13    23    33    43    53  28  
 4     4    14    24    34    44    54  29  
 5    NA    15    25    NA    45    NA  28.3
 6     6    16    26    36    46    56  31  
 7     7    17    27    37    47    57  32  
 8    NA    NA    28    38    NA    NA  NA  
 9     9    19    29    39    49    59  34  
10    10    20    30    40    50    60  35
```

This is leveraging `rowwise` and `c_across` which basically means operating on row level, so you can use vectorized functions such as `sum`, `mean` etc. in their usual way (also with `case_when`).

`c_across` also has a `cols` argument where you can specify which columns you want to take into account. For example, if you'd like to take into account columns `1:6`, you can specify this as:

```
df %>% 
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(
    mean = case_when(
      sum(is.na(c_across(1:6))) < 4 ~ mean(c_across(), na.rm = TRUE),
      TRUE ~ NA_real_)
  ) %>% ungroup()
```

Alternatively, if you'd e.g. like to take into account all columns except column number 2, you would do `c_across(-2)`. You can also use column names, e.g. for the first example `c_across(a:f)` (all columns) or for the second `c_across(-b)` (all columns except `b`).

This is implemented internally in `dplyr`, but you could also do usual vector subsetting with taking the whole `c_across()` (which defaults to all columns, i.e. `everything()`) and do e.g. `c_across()[1:6]` or `c_across()[-2]`.

Comment: Thank you, I didn´t come across rowwise and c_across yet. The problem is, there are more NA´s in my original df in the row but I want to count it only in specific columns. Should´ve made that clear in my example. With your solution I have to create a new df with only the columns i want to calculate the mean with, right?

Comment: @EmKau, no need for creating a new `df`, you can leverage existing argument within `c_across` or subset your vector with `[` - have explained it in the post now. However, if you work with simple examples (no grouping, etc.), then `base` solutions should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

We can create an index first and then do the assignment based on the index

```
i1 <- rowSums(!is.na(df)) >=3
df$Mean[i1] <- rowMeans(df[i1,], na.rm = TRUE)

df
#    a  b  c  d  e  f     Mean
#1   1 11 21 31 41 51 26.00000
#2  NA 12 NA NA 42 NA       NA
#3   3 13 23 33 43 53 28.00000
#4   4 14 24 34 44 54 29.00000
#5  NA 15 25 NA 45 NA 28.33333
#6   6 16 26 36 46 56 31.00000
#7   7 17 27 37 47 57 32.00000
#8  NA NA 28 38 NA NA       NA
#9   9 19 29 39 49 59 34.00000
#10 10 20 30 40 50 60 35.00000
```